# Dependence of resistance of fuse on length

Tags: electric-current, electrical-resistance, short-circuits

Resistance is proportional to the length. Then why is the resistance of fuse independent of length? Should it not change with a change in length?

Comment: This doesn't seem right - do you have a source?

Comment: i meant that why is its working not dependent on length but only cross sectional area.oure teacher said so and so does quora.but explanation is not clear.thanks

Comment: Ok, that is a different question. I will have a go at answering it below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fuses work by breaking up due to heat. The total 'heat' per unit time produced by a wire of resistance $R$ is given by:
$$P=I^2R$$
if the wire is completely uniform then we can replace $R$ with:
$$R=\frac{\rho L}{A}$$
where $\rho$ is the resistivity (a property of the material rather then the fuse), $L$ the fuses length and $A$ its cross sectional area. Hence we get:
$$P=\frac{\rho L}{A}I^2$$
If we again assume the wire is uniform to an approximation the 'heat' will be released at uniformly along its length. Thus the total 'heat' released per unit length is:
$$P_L=\frac{\rho}{A}I^2$$
It is this qunatity which will determine the rise in temperature of the fuse and hence when it breaks. You can see it depends on three parameters; $\rho$ the resistivity, $A$ the cross sectional area and $I$ the current. For a given fuse $\rho$ and $A$ will be fixed and thus $I$ determines the amount of heat released and ultimately when the fuse will break. This is why fuses are rated as e.g. $3A$.

Comment: but what if we increase the length.the resistance (of the overall circuit) increases and so dose current.that means that the working of the fuse is dependent on the length.is that right?thanks

Comment: @daboss Ye that is true, so increasing the length has an indirect affect on the working of the fuse due to its change on the current $I$.

Comment: Okay. tnx Quantum spaghettification(cool name!!)